# Invalid column index in preparedStatement

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert a value in a DB table and I keep stumbling on the Invalid Column Index error.

Here's a code sample:

```
        String insertNewAlarmStat =
            "insert into alarmes (id_alarm, alarm_key, id_notif, sever, urgency, date_hour_start, date_hour_modif, date_hour_end, " +
                    "state, state_rec, date_hour_rec,  id_user_rec, id_system_rec, " +
                    "type, cause, " +
                    "num_events, id_entity_g, type_entity_g, " +
                    "desc_entity_g, problem, " +
                    "time_urg_act, max_urg_act, time_end, time_arq, lim, rec_oblig, dn, num_events_ps, id_alarm_o, id_notif_o, text_ad, domain, date_hour_reg) " +
                    "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, SYSDATE)";
    PreparedStatement prpstmt = null ;
    try {
        prpstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertNewAlarmStat);

        prpstmt.setInt(1, randomNumberGenerator());
        prpstmt.setString(2, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(3, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setInt(4, randomNumberGenerator());
        prpstmt.setInt(5, 8);
        prpstmt.setInt(6, 8524);
        prpstmt.setString(7, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(8, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(9, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(10, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(11, "KABOOM");
        prpstmt.setInt(12, 8);
        prpstmt.setDate(13, getCurrentDate());
        prpstmt.setDate(14, getCurrentDate());
        prpstmt.setDate(15, getCurrentDate());
        prpstmt.setDate(16, getCurrentDate());
        prpstmt.setInt(17, 43);
        prpstmt.setString(18, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(19, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(20, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(21, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setInt(22, 2);
        prpstmt.setInt(23, 224);
        prpstmt.setInt(24, 2);
        prpstmt.setInt(25, 224);            
        prpstmt.setInt(26, 2);
        prpstmt.setInt(27, 4);          
        prpstmt.setInt(28, 2);  
        prpstmt.setString(29, null);
        prpstmt.setString(30, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        prpstmt.setString(31, UUID.randomUUID().toString());            
        prpstmt.setInt(32, 2);  

        prpstmt.execute();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've tried to remove the `prpstmt` from 13 to 16 but it complains that those indexes are missing, I've tried other stuff as well but I can't get this to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are preparing 32 values but you have 27 ? I dont know is this is how java prepared statements work

Comment: There are 28, if I counted correctly. Also, the setting of various database IDs using (presumably) pseudo-random numbers is *highly* questionable.

Comment: Also, there are a *lot* of "magic numbers" in this code.

Comment: they're supposed to be magic eheh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 33 columns in this insert statement.  There are 33 values -- 28 `?` place holders and 5 literal values (`sysdate`).  The indexes in the `setXYZ` methods refer to the index of the `?` placeholders, not the index into the values of the insert statement.

For the `sysdate` values, you don't need to do anything, so remove those calls to `setDate`.  But for values beyond the first 4 `sysdate`s, you just need to use the next value, which is `13`, not `17`.

```
prpstmt.setInt(1, randomNumberGenerator());
// snip
prpstmt.setInt(12, 8);
// calls to `setDate(13-16, getCurrentDate());` removed
prpstmt.setInt(13, 43);  // changed 17 to 13
// snip
prpstmt.setInt(28, 2);   // changed 32 to 28
```

**What is** `sysdate`?

`sysdate` is an Oracle function that returns the current `date/timestamp`, equivalent to `Calendar.getInstance()` in Java. For the purposes of `JDBC`, it's a value that is already supplied in the insert statement.

Comment: can you explain what is sysdate please? so I can fully understand your answer in order to vote u up

Comment: I guess is system date ?

Comment: @KickButtowski `sysdate` is an Oracle function that returns the current date/timestamp, equivalent to `Calendar.getInstance()` in Java.  For the purposes of JDBC, it's a value that is already supplied in the insert statement.

Comment: after doing this I have ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Answer (score 2):

remove

```
prpstmt.setDate(13, getCurrentDate());
prpstmt.setDate(14, getCurrentDate());
prpstmt.setDate(15, getCurrentDate());
prpstmt.setDate(16, getCurrentDate());
```

and instead of 17, start from 13 again..

?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, SYSDATE

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10,11,12,SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE,13,14.... etc

Comment: this answer has been flagged as a low quality answer. please post some explanation to your post.

Comment: after doing this, I keep getting 
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER

Comment: that is an oracle error. Try passing the same parameters as input to the procedure and run it from PL/SQL developer or whichever client youre using. Then you can debug which input is giving you that error.

Answer (score 0):

Your query `String` contains 28 question marks, I wrote a program to count for you

```
String str = "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, "
    + "SYSDATE, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, SYSDATE)";
int count = 0;
for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (ch == '?') {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

So, you can't bind 32 parameters. I think your

```
 prpstmt.setDate(13, getCurrentDate());
 prpstmt.setDate(14, getCurrentDate());
 prpstmt.setDate(15, getCurrentDate());
 prpstmt.setDate(16, getCurrentDate());
```

Are hard coded to `SYSDATE` in the query. So, remove the four `SYSDATE`(s) in the middle of the query

```
"(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, "
+ "?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, SYSDATE)";
```

And you'd have 32.